# Connecting to SAS dataset using OLE DB in QlikView

Tags: sas, oledb, qlikview

I'm trying to use an OLEDB connection to connect to my SAS datasets from QlikView.

I am able to set up the connection, but I am not able to load my data. Executing the data import results in the following error: "the local provider does not currently support sql processing"

My loading code looks like this:

```
LOAD "account",
balance,
"open_closed";
SQL SELECT *
FROM "BASE_DATA";
```

Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: We read SAS data into QlikView using SAS ODBC driver that connects to SAS/SHARE

Comment: @StigEide: Please add this as an answer, as it offers a good workaround for the OP's issue...

Answer (score 0):

We read SAS data into QlikView using SAS ODBC driver that connects to SAS/SHARE.
This requires that you have one of the following three:
1. SAS/SPD Server
2. SAS/SHARE Server
3. SAS locally on desktop (will not work on server license)

Comment: I have tried this solution but it keeps resulting in an error stating: "SQL##f - SqlState: IM006, ErrorCode: 0, ErrorMsg: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Driver's SQLSetConnectAttr failed" @stigEide

Comment: I have tried setup instructions as per a QlikView tutorial. FYI, I do have SAS installed locally and I'm trying to connect to a local SAS server. @stigEide

Comment: This page goes through setting up SAS ODBC against local data: http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/odbcdref/63284/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n170ibo0gfz633n1x7xx5pcxqtas.htm

Comment: I'm afraid that is exactly what I've done. And the error still occurs.

Comment: Remember that ODBC against local data only works when Operating System in `proc setinit` output is `WIN`